# Can you use Syntastic in Vim over a subset of code in a file?

Tags: plugin-syntastic

I use Vim as my main text editor and use Syntastic to assist with linting. I am editing large legacy python files (some upwards of 50,000 lines) and would like to run `SyntasticCheck` over a range or a portion of the file instead of the entire file. Linting the entire file can be slow and displays many irrelevant syntax/styling errors/warnings that are not relevant to my work in that file.

I have read the Syntastic documentation and did not find anything. Anything built into Vim?

```
Vim - 8.1(compiled Sep 30 2019) from homebrew
Syntastic - 3.10.0-1
```

Comment: No.  Syntastic works by running linters against _files_, outside Vim.  It has no notion of buffers, marked lines etc. that exist only inside Vim.

Comment: Ah, that's too bad. Thanks

Comment: Syntastic has the ability to filter messages, but this doesn't seem to work with line ranges (`:help syntastic_quiet_messages`).  Maybe you can ask [them](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic/issues), if they could add that feature. Doesn't help with slow linting though.